# Downloading file in angularjs/html C# (front-end application)

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to perform the download operation of below file types.

```
1. .txt,.pdf,.xlsx,.jpg,.png,.xls
```

My application is Angularjs and WebApi

```
fron-end- angularjs
back-end - webapi
```

I have created anchor tag by specifying the href attribute of file path like below

```
<a href="http://x.com/sample.txt" target="_self" download="xx">sample</a>
```

the above one will download the file, it is working fine.We can download the file in webapi too.

below code snippet to perform the download file option in webapi

```
public HttpResponseMessage DownLoadFile(string FileName, string fileType)  
        {  
            Byte[] bytes = null;  
            if (FileName != null)  
            {  
                string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache), FileName));  
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);  
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);  
                bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);  
                br.Close();  
                fs.Close();  
            }  

            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);  
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);  
            result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);  
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(fileType);  
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")  
            {  
                FileName = FileName  
            };  
            return (result);  
        }
```

above code snippet refereed from below link

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/1d3119/file-upload-and-download-using-html5-file-uploader-control-a851/

what is the best or preferred way of downloading files in webapplication ?

Comment: What is your real purpose of downloading? Do you just want user to get a link to use web browser's default behavior to download a file locally to user or do you want user to save the file to a server directory or any other persistent provider? If you want user to download a file locally why it has to do with WebApi on server?

Comment: @Nathan I want user to download the file locally.  Those files are actually saved somewhere in server. I will call the above webapi from angularjs then that webapi will return the response to angularjs function

Comment: Then you just need to map server path to your service with permission control and return a Url string to bind to <a href="{{DownloadUrl}}"> or <a href="#" onclick="javascript: xxx">.

Comment: @Nathan yes using anchor tag itself i can download the file. my concern is is that a best way of downloading a file in webapplication ?

Comment: Forget about the word "best". There is no "the best" in program management's perspective and you know I'm right. I would rather ask you what's your concern towards this implementation?